# Best approach for composing UIViews to create complex views?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

**Transitioning from the web-stack** to **iOS wonderland**, I am finding it hard to understand how to re-structure my thoughts for MVC and effectively structure my UI on iOS.

### Premise:

- In the web-stack:

  - Controller generally corresponds to a URL and view represents the page.
  - Views have ways to not-repeat code with CSS +Javascript + fragments.
- In iOS:

  - Once on a new screen which correspond to a UIViewController.
  - We have a UIView which composes its own UIViews
  - UIViews exists with UIViews, UIViewController with UIViews, UIViewController with inline UIViews
  - We definitely delegate heavy-lifting or data logic to **nearest controller**
  - It feels mostly **View first** in the iOS which is great

### Question:

What is the best way to think about composing views to my `self.view` with:

- A view as `UIView` class
- A view occurring as `UIViewController` with an associated `UIView` class.
- A view occurring as `UIViewController` with inline `UIView`

### Example view hierarchy:

```
------------------------------
|             A              |
|                            |
|    --------------------    |
|    |        B         |    |
|    |                  |    |
|    |  --------------  |    |
|    |  |     C      |  |    |
|    |  |            |  |    |
|    |  |            |  |    |
|    |  |            |  |    |
|    |  |            |  |    |
|    |  |            |  |    |
|    |  |            |  |    |
|    |  --------------  |    |
|    |                  |    |
|    --------------------    |
|                            |
------------------------------
```

### [Details to be Specific] My ~uncomfortable~ experiences:

- `A` might `[self addView:B_view]` (If B was just UIView)
- `A` might also `[self addView:B_viewController.view]` (If B had a view controller)
- `A` might also `[B setChildView:C_view]`
- We can have `B_viewController.delegate = A` & `C_viewController.delegate = A`
- We can have `B_viewController.delegate = A` & `C_view.delegate = B`
- After all these cases co-existing, we have to think about the bounds
- I see C's concerns answered by A via long delegate chains.

**The logic is scattered across delegates, viewControllers and views**.

### Separating Concerns - But How ?

Apart from the argument **"abstract well and separation of concerns"** that can improve above experiences. I believe its the bleeding of viewController and viewController.view being composed to easily cause extensive coupling.

This quickly becomes **confusing** and feels like **spaghetti** and hard to control despite efforts.

**That said,**

- What are the best practices to address above pitfalls ?
- What are the absolute don'ts ?
- How do we avoid long delegate chains when its hard to come up with good arguments since when having delegate its effectively saying you can handle this better ?

Comment: Question comes from practical experience, I believe its not just me and should serve as a great resource.

Comment: Great question, don't understand the downvote. Not sure I can answer though, I often ask myself the same question.

Comment: Good question. The OP has done his homework and structured the question well. Please add a reason for downvoting.

Comment: If this is marked as "too broad", what is the place in Stack Website to ask such questions?

Comment: Since what you are asking for is a question related to application architecture, I advise you to read the following article on iOS Application Architecture https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-architecture-patterns-ecba4c38de52#.gjp0yrwkn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps, what you are dealing is with the MVC - Massive View Controllers dilemma. Here is an interesting read where Marcus speaks of managing code effectively by putting the code where it belongs, networking layer, persistence layer or the presentation layer(ideally the viewcontroller).

http://www.cimgf.com/2015/09/21/massive-view-controllers/

Apart from the delegation pattern we also have block/closure based approach that might help to clean up the code.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html

In general, Robert C. Martin's clean code approach could be of help here. The way to implement it through something called as VIPER architecture. Here is a tutorial on that.

https://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/viper/

Objective C, as a language embraces the delegation pattern and it is a standard practice to use it for most of one's concerns.

Welcome to the iOS platform.

Answer (score 3):

I failed at asking similarly broad questions at stackoverflow - seems like community favors more specific technical question. But I'll give it a shot. Keep in mind that all following are my opinions and not hard and fast rules.

I feel like it is a composite question about message passing and design patterns. In terms of components communication (whether they are views or controller) there are many ways to go about it, each has it's `+` and `-` (or rather use cases). There is: delegation, responder chain, blocks, notifications, reactive signal - just to name a few.

## TL;DR

- My personal preference is definitely to keep the view as simple as possible and put the business logic someplace else (depending on the pattern you chose) allowing for better composition.
- Your gut feeling aligns with mine: whenever your component (view or view controller) is doing `self.superview` or `self.parentViewController` (some say even `self.navigationController`) it probably violates encapsulation and there is a better way.
- Long delegate chains is definitely an issue. Sometimes they are easy to follow, sometimes not, but it's not the worst thing in the world, although chances are there is a better way to handle communication.

Following are few random observations that might lead you somewhere (or might not).

## MVC is a quick (and dirty) way to get people in iOS

In my opinion, MVC is a great pattern for small project (it is easy from "easy vs simple"). But from personal experience it quickly gets out of hands when the complexity of the screen you're working on grows. Tendency is for the controller to handle everything from user interaction to networking and it becomes a 1k-long monster really quick.

Sadly a lot in iOS architecture is relying on `UIViewController`. Often it inevitably becomes a first point of contact of your code with OS, but it doesn't have to handle everything internally. Instead it can route responsibilities to appropriate components, i.e.

```
func loginButtonDidTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
  loginManager.beginLogin(from: self)
  analytics.reportLogin(with: sender)
  // ...
}
```

## It is okay to compose controllers, too

I didn't quite notice from your description, but if you prefer to go with MVC it is a completely valid option to compose controllers. It is a very common situation when building for iPad but even on iPhone every screen can easily include completely independent pieces where every one of them is a separate `ViewController`, then you should look into what's called "UIViewController containment". Mostly it allows for better separation and reuse, but again, doesn't solve the main issue.

## Definitely explore other patterns

If you are reading this, you are very eager to learn In this case, I'd suggest not to stop on MVC. There are many interesting design patterns that might or might not be suitable for your particular needs. MVVM was (is?) quite popular. Lately unidirectional flow seems to be the new hot thing. Inspired by JS's Redux. It is a very much departure from MVC and I suggest checking this project out https://github.com/ReSwift/ReSwift if you are interested.

Sadly like any architectural question there is no right and wrong - there are only things that work for you and your team or not. And I'd love to hear other perspectives before question gets closed as "too broad"

Sorry if this is completely not what you asked for, let me know if there are any particular aspects you'd like to discuss.

Answer (score 1):

- You can have one ViewController
- Have UIViews separated to ViewController. It should not be tightly coupled with viewController.
- Have your View login in UIView class itself. Create its own delegate and protocols. and use it in any viewcontroller.
- add viewcontroller to viewcontroller is not a good solution.
- You can also move to MVVM where every view will have its logic part in its View Model, But it can be confusing at beginning.
- Try to make UIViews separated to ViewControllers.

Answer (score 1):

As someone who has done a fair amount of iOS programming, and is now spending lots of time in angular dev, here's a few quick thoughts:

A `UIView` represents the fundamental screen building block; that is, it compromises a view, some data, and the logic to render that data on the view.  Thus it can be used to draw some text or graphics, or it can contain any number of subviews that have the same ability.  In the Angular world, a `UIView` would be (somewhat) equivalent to a `Component` that encapsulates `HTML`, `CSS`, `JavaScript`, etc, but could also include other components.

As you know, iOS provides many pre-built, native UIView's - `UILabel`, `UIButton`, `UITable`, etc, and these are suitable for the bulk of application needs.

A `UIViewController` has a more structural function than a `UIView`.  It integrates with the navigation framework so that the developer can quickly change the context for the user.  It contains a "main" `UIView` which serves as the base platform for the context, containing any number of native and custom `UIView's`.  Its purpose is to help configure those `UIViews` *given the current app context*.

If a `UIViewController` is configuring a `UIView` in ways that are not limited to the current app context, then the `UIView` should probably be extended into a custom object.   That way it can self-manage and is easier to reuse in other contexts.

One other thing:

Delegates are great when appropriate, but `NSNotification` is a simple, powerful way to observe changes while avoiding the spaghetti of object dependencies.